# ActiveRecord Relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 Models:

`Group`

`Feed`

`FeedItem`

A Group has many Feeds and Feeds have many FeedItems

Is there anyway I can get all the Feeds in a Groups FeedItems from the Group?

I guess something like `group.feeds.feed_items` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) association. Add the following line to your `Group` model

```
has_many :feed_items, :through => :feeds
```

After that, you can access all the `FeedItems` in a group via `group.feed_items`